# DOM Exception in Heatmap.js for Leaflet in Safari

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap

I'm using Heatmap.js(http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) to display a heatmap in a Leaflet map. In the heatmap datapoints object I set the radius of each point manually by setting.

```
datapoint.radius = radiusCoeff * (datapoint.value / geodata.max);
```

where geodata.max is the maximum value of the dataset. These values varies from 1 up to 500 million. The reason I set the radius property instead of the 'value' property is because this gave a better representation of the dataset than changing the value property.

I set the dataset using:

```
heatmapLayer.setData(geodata);
```

In Safari I get the following error:

```
DOMException
code: 11
constructor: DOMExceptionConstructor
line: 390
message: "INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11"
name: "INVALID_STATE_ERR"
sourceId: 2057773152
sourceURL: "http://localhost:51612/app/libs/heatmapjs/build/heatmap.js"
__proto__: DOMExceptionPrototype
```

- The code line that is referred to in the exception is
  "shadowCtx.drawImage(tpl, rectX, rectY)" in the heatmap source code.
- The app only fails in Safari for desktop and iOS and only when I
  manually set the radius property for each datapoint.
- I am currently using the develop branch of
  heatmap.js(https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/tree/develop) and the
  latest version of leaflet

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This would need a live example of exactly what you're trying to get running, especially given that you've modified the original library.